# Como fechar janela modal?

Tags: javascript

Este código funciona corretamente com um *iframe* de um filme online. O problema quando fecho *modal* fecha a janela, mas o áudio continua rolando no fundo. Quem aqui consegue arrumar este código?

```
<style>
.modalDialog {
position: fixed;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(9, 9, 9, 1);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
 .modalDialog:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
width: 800px;
position: relative;
margin: 5% auto;

-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px #000;
}
 .close {
background: #606061;
display: block;
// Botão de pause
close.onPress = function(){
    close.modalDialog();
}
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: -12px;
text-align: center;
top: -10px;
width: 24px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 12px;
-moz-border-radius: 12px;
border-radius: 12px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
.modalpic {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
display: block;
border: 4px solid #ffffff;
border-radius: 30%;
box-shadow: 3px 6px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 6px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 6px 8px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
margin-right: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
});
</style>
<a href="#abrirModal">VideoPW</a>
<div id="abrirModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a class="close"href="#close" ><img src="js/fechar.png"></a>
  <iframe src="http://video.pw/e/s2yr2oyvr5vtlra/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="854px" height="480px"></iframe>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não está faltando uma chave na function do seu .close ?

Comment: rafael e como por essa chave function

Comment: Você abriu a função -> function() **{** mas esqueceu de fechar -> **}**, como está a situação já conseguiu resolver ?

Comment: nao tem como vc fazer este codigo fechar o audio pra nao entendo disso ja peguei esse codigo assim

Comment: o link do vídeo consta que não existe mais para que possamos testar. Removi do seu código no final do css o item "});", alterei o comentário para " /* Botão de pause */ ", só e funcionou, porém preciso do link do vídeo para ter uma precisão.